# Java Thread Interruption - restoring versus catching and swallowing

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading the book Java Concurrency in Practice and there's a section on what to do when a thread is interrupted. There are a couple of options:

1. Propagate the InterruptedException
2. Restore the interrupt (by calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`)

Then there is one other option:

> The only situation in which it is acceptable to swallow an interrupt is when you are extending `Thread` and therefore control all the code higher up on the call stack.

I don't understand why we can swallow the interrupt when extending `Thread` and not when implementing `Runnable`.